# Marklogic rest api : long running queries

Tags: marklogic

We are using `Marklogic REST-Api` for interaction with `Marklogic` db for my product development.

Now I would like to find out the top long running queries or expensive queries or expensive REST-API call which I have in my application, does Marklogic have any provide any way to achieve the same ?

I have gone through this below link but I think its more towards if I am using `Xquery`

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/query_meters#id_37027

Answer (score 3):

From the top of my head, there are a number of things you can look at:

- Monitoring Dashboard (http://localhost:8002/dashboard)
- Monitoring History (http://localhost:8002/history)
- Cluster/Host status in Admin UI (http://localhost:8001, Status tabs)
- And MarkLogic provides [plugins to integrate with monitoring tools like Nagios](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/nagios)

Not entirely sure these provide a direct answer to what you are looking for, but definitely worth a look.

For further reading, I'd recommend reading the [Monitoring guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/monitoring/intro).

HTH!

Comment: thanks a lot it helps to some extent.. In dashboard it says "5 longest running queries since xxxx time",do we have a way to retrieve the actual query which took so long and the time it occurred ?

Comment: The access logs will tell you what URLs were requested and when, though they won't show POST (etc) bodies.